# Чтение данных из Excel в С#

Tags: c#, excel

Доброго всем дня!
 Подскажите как обратится к уже открытой книге Excel если она открыта в отдельном окне, то-есть Excel файлы могут быть открыты в одном окне и существует по крайней мере еще одно окно где открыт файл Excel
Вот такой код перебирает файлы только в одном окне!

```
string ExcelPath2 = "C:\\Users\\Mari\\Documents\\Итоги.xlsx";
 Excel.Application xlApp = null;
            Excel.Workbook WorkBook = null;
     xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
//Затем среди них находится нужная.
    foreach (Excel.Workbook Book in xlApp.Workbooks)
     {
      if (ExcelPath.ToUpper().Equals(Book.FullName.ToUpper()))
      {
       WorkBook = Book;
       Excel.Worksheet sheet = xlApp.Worksheets[1];
       var cellValue = (Double)(sheet.Cells[2, 3] as Excel.Range).Value;
       Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
       break;
      }
     }
```

Как быть? Подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") всегда будет ссылаться на последнее открытое окно Excel (последний открытый экземпляр "last instance of Excel application").

Вот это то, что вы ищете (Get Collection of All Running Excel Instances): https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080611/Get-a-Collection-of-All-Running-Excel-Instances